# No sound from speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel

Just installed a new Kubuntu 13.10. It seems the Intel HDA sound card are recognized as a HDMI(Digital) output rather than both an analog output and a digital one. AlsaInfo is [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=acaf75aa29aae2895bc0b861fb40b7b1521fe576)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to start play an video or audio file and let it play to know when your sound will start working
Just open the terminal and run `alsamixer` and then using arrows browse through playback devices and unmute muted (M key) devices until you hear a sound.